# Windows, DHCP Server Reservation - finding free IP address

Tags: windows, powershell, server, dhcp

I'm trying to write up a script which would find (and later add reservation) for DHCP device. The problem I'm having that there is one scope, and within this scope we manually divided into different IP ranges where certain type of devices should be added.

E.g. the scope 10.92.0.0/24 and we assign ranges as

10.92.0.10-20 for iPhones etc.
10.92.0.10.50 for Android phones etc.

I've got the point where the script can go through the IP ranges I provide to it, and either GET DHCP reservation or show error. I've been thinking that first Error could be taken as the free IP.

Any ideas anyone? :)

```
    # Get DHCP Scope
$Start = 100
$End = 140
$DHCPServer = "dhcpserver.company.com"

# Find Free IP address
    #It can use to get DHCP reservation by IP and find the one which returns error - which can be used as the free one - loop done
    #Now how to tell it to stop when the error occures?
While ($Start -le $End) {
    $IP = "10.92.0.$Start"
    Write-Host "Reservation for: $IP" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ComputerName $DHCPServer -IPAddress $IP
    $Start++
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can assign the output of `Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation` to a variable, then act on that:

```
While ($Start -le $End) {
    $IP = "10.92.0.$Start"
    $reservation = Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ComputerName $DHCPServer -IPAddress $IP -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if($reservation){
        Write-Host "Reservation for: $IP" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $reservation
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "No reservation found for: $IP" -ForegroundColor Red
        break #comment out to continue through all IPs in Scope
    }

    $Start++
}
```

Comment: There is a dedicated cmdlet for getting free DHCP server leases: `Get-DhcpServerv4FreeIPAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the dedicated cmdlet `Get-DhcpServerv4FreeIPAddress`?

```
Get-DhcpServerv4FreeIPAddress -ScopeId "192.168.1.0" -StartAddress "192.168.1.100" -EndAddress "192.168.1.140" -ComputerName "dhcpserver.company.com"
```

Comment: In help it said it goes through the list of available leases and reservations, I'm after only the reservations.